# SQL - contains only combinations of specific numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, select

There is a Table (let T) with column (let C) containing only numbers. I wish to retrieve the numbers using select that are only a combination of e.g 1,2,3 like 123123, 111111, 112113, 231213 etc. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something that only uses standard SQL and which will work in all RDBMSs:

```
select c from t
where replace(replace(replace(c, '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', '') = ''
and length(c) > 0
```

For those that support regex, like Postgres:

```
select c from t
where c rlike '^[123]+$'
```

Oracle:

```
select c from t
where regexp_like(c,'^[123]+$');
```

Comment: The OP *is* using Oracle. What are the chances? :D

Comment: I believe the standard SQL could not work in Oracle, due to null issues

Comment: @alek it will work. If the column is null, the result of the replaces will be null, which will *not* be "true"

Comment: I mean that null can be an issue in the check, even if the column is not null. For example, `select case when '' = '' then 'true' else 'false' end from dual` gives false in Oracle.

Comment: @alek I consider that a bug in Oracle: Unbelievably, `select case when '' is null then 'true' else 'false' end from dual` returns "true"! A zero-length string is **not** null. I found a work-around that handles this. Yet another reason to not use Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out that a standard SQL solution may not work properly in Oracle.

With a table like this:

```
create table t(c) as (
                select '1233' from dual union all
                select '1XX3' from dual union all
                select 'XX'   from dual union all
                select ''     from dual 
             )
```

The standard approach gives:

```
SQL> select c from t
  2  where replace(replace(replace(c, '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', '') = ''
  3    and c <> '';

no rows selected
```

the reason is in the way Oracle handles empty strings :

```
SQL> select c,
  2         case when replace(replace(replace(c, '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', '') = '' and c <> '' then 'MATCH'
  3              else 'NO MATCH'
  4         end as checkMatch
  5  from t;

C    CHECKMAT
---- --------
1233 NO MATCH
1XX3 NO MATCH
XX   NO MATCH
     NO MATCH
```

In a simple example:

```
SQL> select case when '' = '' then 'true' else 'false' end
  2  from dual;

CASEW
-----
false
```

In Oracle, the check should be against `NULL`:

```
SQL> select c,
  2         case when replace(replace(replace(c, '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', '') is null and c is not null then 'MATCH'
  3              else 'NO MATCH'
  4         end as checkMatch
  5  from t;

C    CHECKMAT
---- --------
1233 MATCH
1XX3 NO MATCH
XX   NO MATCH
     NO MATCH
```

So an Oracle solution without regexp could be:

```
SQL> select c from t
  2  where replace(replace(replace(c, '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', '') is null
  3    and c is not null;

C
----
1233
```